# SKPhysicsBody change animation/physics speed

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

Is there any way to change the animation/physics speed of physicsbody?

I want the update method to be called 60 times a second still, I just want everything on the screen to move slowly, but still have the same property values (ie a velocity (10, 10) would still do the same thing it would just be in slow motion..)

Is there any way to induce this or is there a built in function?

One thing I can think of is dividing every movement property value by two and making gravity half what it is, but I don't think you can set the gravity and I'm not sure that would work anyway physics-wise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to slow down the physics simulation by a factor of two, use:

```
myScene.physicsWorld.speed = 0.5;
```

Comment: This works if you also change the world's gravity. Changing the speed doesn't affect the rate of gravity which is what I wanted to do additionaly

Comment: @maxhud On my system, the code I provided (i.e. setting the `speed` property of the entire `SKPhysicsWorld` object to 0.5) does also decrease gravity by a factor of two, without having to update the `gravity` property as well. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: I think gravity might have to be decreased by a factor of 4 because it is an exponential function. Everything appeared really "heavy" after I changed the speed property. Try it yourself. It doesn't just slow down the whole thing. It makes it disproportionate

Comment: Nope definitely not the case. I can upload two versions and show you if you really don't believe me and think it's important

Comment: @maxhud I've run into so many problems with Sprite Kit over the past few hours alone that I'm not surprised that you're having issues.